# TFS 2008: How do I sync build names with version numbers?

Tags: tfsbuild

Currently my TFS build agent using the current date as the build name. For example, "Intranet_20100707.1" would be today's first build. Currently I use "1.2.*" as my assembly version number where 1 and 2 are manually incremented.

How can I sync the build names with my application's version number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `BuildNumber` property. We do this in a custom task that implements the `BuildNumberOverrideTarget` override, but if you are already manually manipulating your assembly version number then you can just assign the updated number to `BuildNumber`.

If you still want text like the project name (*Intranet*) on the front then you can either prepend that to the start of BuildNumber, or do the copy yourself to the drop location.